# How to manage development and installed versions of a shared library?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

In short: This question is basically about telling Linux to load the development version of the `.so` file for executables in the dev directory and the installed `.so` file for others.

In long: Imagine a shared library, let's call it `libasdf.so`. And imagine the following directories:

```
/home/user/asdf/lib: libasdf.so
/home/user/asdf/test: ... perform_test
/opt/asdf/lib: libasdf.so
/home/user/jkl: ... use_asdf
```

In other words, you have a development directory for your library (`/home/user/asdf`) and you have an installed copy of its previous stable version (`/opt/asdf`) and some other programs using it (`/home/user/jkl`).

My question is, how can I tell Linux, to load `/home/user/asdf/lib/libasdf.so` when executing `/home/user/asdf/test/perform_test` and to load `/opt/asdf/lib/libasdf.so` when executing `/home/user/jkl/use_asdf`? Note that, even though I specify the directory by `-L` during link, Linux uses other methods (for example `/ect/ld.so.conf` and `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`) to find the `.so` file.

The reason I need such a thing is that, of course the executables in the development directory need to link with the latest version of the library, while the other programs, would want to use the stable version.

Putting `../lib` in the library path doesn't seem like a secure idea, not to mention not completely correct since you can't run the test from a different directory.

One solution I thought about is to have `perform_test` link with `libasdf-dev.so` and upon install, copy `libasdf-dev.so` as `libasdf.so` and have others link with that. This solution has one problem though. Imagine the following additional directory:

```
/home/user/asdf/tool: ... use_asdf_too
```

Which gets installed to:

```
/opt/asdf/bin: use_asdf_too
```

In my solution, it is unknown what `use_asdf_too` should be linked against. If linked against `libasdf.so`, it wouldn't work properly if invoked from the dev directory and if linked against `libasdf-dev.so`, it wouldn't work properly if invoked from the installed location.

What can I do? How is this managed by other people?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installed shared objects usually don't *just* end with ".so". Usually they also include their **soname**, such as `libadsf.so.42.1`. The .so file for development is typically a symlink to a fully-versioned filename. The linker will look for the .so file and resolve it to the full filename, and the loader will then load the fully-versioned library instead.

Comment: So any time I reinstall the library, I would have to immediately make the development directory produce a different .so file with a different version so they won't get mixed up?

Comment: The build routine for the library should already be adding the library version to the filename.

Comment: Of course. I meant that I should remember to update that version (which is again another "of course"). Thanks!

Comment: Just for completeness, it seems impossible to do with `libxxx.so.version`, since you can't use `-l` option with that, and given the library directly to the linker seems to put the address with the name too (what `ldd` reported). I resorted to using `libxxx-version.so` and a `libxxx.so` symlink to it.